# Whats the package name for WebKitGtk dependency gobject-introspection-1.0?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

Im trying to build [WebKitGtk](https://webkitgtk.org) from a [tarball](https://webkitgtk.org/releases/webkitgtk-2.22.5.tar.xz). I am getting the following error

```
-- Found ICU data libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so
-- Checking for module 'gobject-introspection-1.0'
--   No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
CMake Error at Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:219 (message):
  GObjectIntrospection is needed for ENABLE_INTROSPECTION.
```

I should do

```
sudo apt -y install ?
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362778/no-package-gobject-introspection-1-0-found-while-deploying-to-heroku)

```
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev
```